# Issues with setting up UITableView sections and rows using fetch request results array and a structure

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I have some problems that require a solution which is beyond my knowledge unfortunately at the moment. 
I perform a fetch request that returns an array of Floors entity object which has 2 attributes (floor number and number of rooms). I want to make a table with the number of sections corresponding the num of floors and the num. of rows in each section corresponding to the number of rooms per floor. I use a struct and 2 for in loops to separate the attributes for the table. The result is baffling me: if i declare one floor it works and a picker in the next vc displays floor "0". If I assign 2 rooms to it I get a giant print response and a table with 10s of rows. Please have a look at the code below and the pictures provided and if someone could help I would be thankful.

```
class RoomAndAlarmTypeTableVC: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

//MARK: - Properties

private var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

private var storedFloors = [Floors]()    

private var resultsArray = [Results]()

//MARK: - Actions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    loadFloorData()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

private func loadFloorData() {
    let floorRequest: NSFetchRequest<Floors> = Floors.fetchRequest()
    do {
        storedFloors = try managedObjectContext.fetch(floorRequest)
        //            tableView.reloadData()
        print("\(storedFloors)")

    } catch {
        print("could not load data from core \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}



// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return resultsArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return resultsArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "house cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewRooomNumberCell

    cell.floorNumberTxt.text = String(storedFloors[indexPath.section].floorNumber)

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return resultsArray[section].sectionName
}
```

}

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storedFloors` is an array of managedObjects, which already has all the information that you need. The number of sections is  `storedFloors.count` and the number of rows is `storedFloors[sectionIndex].numberOfRooms`.  To build a cell the floor is storedFloors[indexPath.section].floorNumber and the room number is simply `indexPath.row`.

The other objects you created are wrong and confusing and should be removed.

Comment: thank you for the answer. It makes perfect sense what you've said but it doesn't display the data correctly. If i assign 1 floor with 2 rooms i get a table with 2 rows with a "1" in each row. This was the reason that I have tried with the struct. I have edited the posted code with what you gave me. If you have time could you please have a look at it?

Comment: replace `cell.floorNumberTxt.text = String(storedFloors[indexPath.section].floorNumber)` with  `cell.floorNumberTxt.text = String(indexPath.row)`

Comment: Hi. Yes I have done it. For 2 floors with 2 rooms each I get only 1 row with "0" as displayed value. I also get a warning in the console: data fault on all the objects.. So there is clearly a problem with the way I have structured the data base. I will post a new question regarding that and I will paste the link here. If you would have a bit of time to look at it and maybe spot the error It would be great. Thank you

Comment: remove `resultsArray` and use storedFloors.

Comment: yes I have done it. I apologise if it is still present in the code displayed. I removed it completely and wrote the solution you provided..I am sure it has to be my core data set up. As I am new to it there must be the problem. I am currently writing my question and I will post you a link asap. Thank you

Comment: I have posted it. I have provided all the code involved so maybe you could spot the errors..Thank you. Kind regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029926/data-fault-when-attempting-to-display-entity-attributes-in-uitableview

Comment: with the core data setup screen shot also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029926/data-fault-when-attempting-to-display-entity-attributes-in-uitableview